# MAMP PRO and imagick 'ImagickException' with message 'FailedToExecuteCommand'

Tags: php, imagick, mamp-pro

I'm actually surprised that this question is not answered yet. So, here's my issue. I'm trying to open a PDF using imagick under MAMP PRO 3.2.1

I've set up a local server and I put the following code in it:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$img = new imagick();

// $img->readImage("filename.jpg");
$img->readImage("filename.pdf");

$img->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);   
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(50);
$img->stripImage(); 

echo "I've just done a bunch of useless stuff!";
?>
```

And instead of getting the response "I've just done a bunch of useless stuff!" I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'FailedToExecuteCommand `"/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/var/tmp/magick-37204WejycxOWotDX%d" "-f/var/tmp/magick-37204yFoZNLVNVn6B" "-f/var/tmp/magick-37204aRp_iZaRakLl"' (-1) @ error/utility.c/SystemCommand/2051' in /Users/Jason/Code/git/imagick-test/web/imagick.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /Users/Jason/Code/git/imagick-test/web/imagick.php(11): Imagick->readimage('projects/26/556...') #1 {main} thrown in /Users/Jason/Code/git/imagick-test/web/imagick.php on line 8

Oddly enough, if I comment out the PDF line and uncomment the JPG line, the code runs without any problems.

Now, I know ghostscript came installed with MAMP PRO, so I don't need to install that or anything, but I don't know why, how, or even what to do about it not being able to read a file in the `/var/tmp/` when my file is in `/Users/Jason/Code/git/imagick-test/web/imagick/` folder. I've done everything but tear my hair out. If you can provide any information, please do.

Comment: What happens when you execute /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/gs yourself, or through PHP with 'exec'?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can run gs myself. I don't know how to php exec it through imagick on MAMP PRO, though.

Comment: I mean this http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php exec. It appears that for probably some permissions reason, Imagick/ImageMagick isn't able to run that command...

Comment: If it helps any, the file it's referencing in the /var/tmp folder does not exist at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to the MAMP Pro developers, and here was their response:

> Hi,
>
> Sorry for the delay. You need to install xQuartz. Follow the link here
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341
>
> http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

I don't see this documented anywhere, so I am updating my question with this answer.

They were apologizing for the delay because I asked them for help right when they were deploying MAMP PRO 3.4.